# Error while submitting transactions in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am running Hyperledger Fabric with 4 peers of 1 organization, 1 orderer and 1 CA. All 4 peers are on different VMs, orderer and CA are running on different VMs. Chaincode is up and running on all the VMs. I want to setup client on a different VM, which can send transaction requests to the network. Using [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/fabcar/invoke.js#L21) code, I have changed the address of VM to my peer0. 
I run the following 2 [files](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/fabcar/enrollAdmin.js) first:

```
node enrollAdmin.js
node registerUser.js
```

I am getting the following error on running the last command:

```
Store path:/root/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/fabcar/hfc-key-store
Successfully loaded admin from persistence
Failed to register: Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authentication failure"}]]
```

I checked the logs of CA container on the . Container log is as follows:

```
2019/04/16 17:34:55 [DEBUG] Received request for /api/v1/register
2019/04/16 17:34:55 [DEBUG] Caller is using a x509 certificate
2019/04/16 17:34:55 [DEBUG] Failed to verify token based on new authentication header requirements: %!s(<nil>)
2019/04/16 17:34:55 [INFO] 192.168.1.22:44826 POST /api/v1/register 401 26 "Untrusted certificate: Failed to verify certificate: x509: 
certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of 
"x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.example.com")"
```

I have copied the same generated crypto material on all the VMs, including the client. How to resolve this error?

UPDATE: When I place the client code on one of the VMs running peer containers, it works fine. Transactions are executed successfully.

Comment: Fabric CA and Orderer are reachable from peers?

Comment: What do you mean by reachable? If I fire transaction from peer's CLI, transactions are successful. I checked logs of CA and orderer. So, they are running fine

Comment: @AlexanderYammine Kindly check the update

Comment: There is something wrong here. The error logs say that the certificate does not match with the FabricCA server. When you enrolled your admin, you used ['ca.example.com'](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/fabcar/enrollAdmin.js#L42) as a FabricCA name's, but the logs say 'ca.org1.example.com', are you sure you changed FabricCA name's in all files and ENV?

Comment: Name of the CA container is ca.example.com itself. [Here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/a0d360311d880dd58aa3672bbffe280ec5cadebe/fabcar/enrollAdmin.js#L42) I just changed the localhost to the IP address of VM containing CA.